# Custom Cart Class in CodeIgniter shows unexpected behaviour

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a custom cart in Code Igniter. New Items are added without problem. But if I add an existing item, instead of increasing the quantity of the item in the cart, nothing happens at all. I just am not being able to figure out where I missed it! Here is my code:

TO clarify a bit;

Suppose I added item (name =  Ray Ban,quanity = 2, price = 2) to cart and then again added 
item (name =  Ray Ban,quanity = 3, price = 20).

I want the item in cart to be (name= Ray Ban, quantity = 5, price = 20 ).

But it is not happening so. Thanks in advance

**Test.php**

```
<?php class Test extends CI_Controller{


function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();

}


function index(){

    $this->load->library('Mycart');

    $item = array(

                     array(
                                        'item'      => 'Mango Fruity',
                                        'price'     => '30',
                                        'quantity'  =>  2

                        ),

                     array(
                                        'item'      => 'Mango Fruitym',
                                        'price'     => '300',
                                        'quantity'  =>  4

                        ),

                     array(
                                        'item'      => 'Mango Fruity',
                                        'price'     => '30',
                                        'quantity'  =>  3

                        )                           

        );

    $this->mycart->add_item($item);


}



}
```

---

**MyCart.php**

---

```
<?php class Mycart {


public $cart_items;
public  $ci;

function __construct(){


    $this->ci           =   &get_instance();

    if($this->ci->session->userdata('cart'))

        $this->cart_items = $this->ci->session->userdata('cart');

    else

        $this->cart_items = array();


}


function add_item($items = 0){

    /* 
        Function Name      : add_item
        Function Author    : Manish Lamichhane
        Function Objective : Add items to cart

        Documentation:


        if(item is present in cart)

            quantity of the item in cart += quantity of item 

        for this it checks the item against all the items available in cart 

        if the item is present in cart,  occurrence flag is set

        after all the cart items are checked for this particular loop (inner forloop)

        once again the value of occurrence is checked

        if occurrence is set, that means the item was already in cart

        and thus the amount of this item is already increased in cart

   but if occurrence is set to 0, this means this particular item is not present in cart

        and thus this has to be added as new item in cart

    */


    if($item = 0){

        return;

    }elseif(is_array($items)){


    $item_already_in_cart = 0; //parameter to check if the added item is already in cart

        foreach($items as $item ){ 


            if(count($this->cart_items)){ //checks if cart is empty


                    foreach($this->cart_items as $cart_item){

                        if($cart_item['item'] == $item['item']){ 

                        /* if item to be added exists in cart,
                           add the quantity of the item in cart */

                        $cart_item['quantity'] += $item['quantity'];

                        $item_already_in_cart++; //flag sets if same item is encountered


                        }


                    }

/*  when control reaches here,
 it means first item to be added it check across all items in cart */

                    if($item_already_in_cart){ 

                        #checks if flag for this particular item is set
                        #if flag is set, it means the item was already in cart and thus quanitity was increased
                        #so the item need not be added in the cart

                        $item_already_in_cart = 0; 


                    }else{

                        #else if the $item_already_in_cart flag is not set, then add the item to cart

                        $this->cart_items[] = $item;

                    }

                }else{

                        $this->cart_items[] = $item; //if the cart was empty 



                }


        }

        echo "<pre>";print_r($this->cart_items);exit;   


    }else{

        return;

    }


}//add_item function ends here



}//class ends here
```

Comment: why are not using cart library.. any reason?

Comment: I wanted to develop a general cart that I can use with other OOP projects as well. Plus, it gives a good feeling when you create something :)

Comment: I am just curious why is the quantity not incremented here: $cart_item['quantity'] += $item['quantity']; This is very weird because I also tried $cart_item['quantity'] = 5. But also its not working. The if condition is fulfilled though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add $this->ci->session->set_userdata($this->cart_items);
So you don't save the cart in the session.
Try to add

```
$this->ci->session->set_userdata($this->cart_items);
```

before

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($this->cart_items);exit;
```

Comment: thanks for the comment Roman. But session has got nothing to do here. If two same items are encountered in the cart, it shall add the quantity and not repeat the items. But that is not happening. I am trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Using reference to variable in foreach loop did the trick!!!

foreach($this->cart_items as **&**$cart_item){

//code here

}